# How to pass enum value to controller with ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to pass my enum value to controller.

I have this enum in my model:

```
public enum Section
{
      Upper,
      Lower
};
```

I want to pass this value through ajax on my controller:

```
$(function () {
  var section='@Section.Upper'//i want to pass Upper value only to my controller.
  alert(section) ///output Upper
 $.ajax({
                url: '/Section/FindSection',
                data: { 'Section': section},
 });
```

In Database table it is storing 1 for upper and 0 for lower.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Generate(int FindSection)
{   
}
```

> Error:The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'FindSection' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Generate(Int32)'

I know i can pass directly pass 1 but i dont want to hardcode because in future if i need to pass any other thing then 
again i have to change the code.

how can i do this???

Comment: Try replacing the word `FindSection` with `Section` in your action method and then run again.

Comment: @HarveySpecter:I cant change my parameter because i have use this method at so many places

Comment: You'll have to change the name at either of those two places. Either in method name in your controller or in the ajax call. They need to be same to be recognized.

Comment: yeah i can change name at may ajax call.but cant i pass like this from ajax:Section.Upper

Comment: Try putting `FindSection` in place of `Section` in the `data` field of your ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass the index of the item you want.

```
public ActionResult Generate(Section section)
{   

}

$(function () {
  //...
 $.ajax({
            url: '/Section/Generate',
            data: { section: 1} //the controller will receive Super.Lower
 });
 //..
})
```

Comment: please dont hardcore this

Comment: @Lacy Jones I'm sorry, I didn't understand. Can you be more clear?

Comment: I mean cant i pass like this from ajax:Section.Upper.passing like this from ajax gives error what i have describe in my question

Answer (score 2):

Change the action code to:

```
public ActionResult Generate(Section Section) {  }
```

Also do not use hardcoded urls in ASP.NET MVC, utilize url helpers instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Generate", "Section")',
    data: { 'Section': section }
 });
```

**Edit:** If changing the method parameter is not an option, than use the correct name in the `ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Generate", "Section")',
    data: { 'FindSection': section }
 });
```

Comment: sorry i cant change my method parameter as it is used at multiple place and so changing it will require changing at many place